# Underscore.js Sum of all methods of some objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there a simple way to sum object methods.

```
var obj = {
    a: {
        aa: 12,
        bb: 4
    },
    b: {
        aa: 5,
        bb: 100
    },
    c: {
        aa: 1,
        bb: 150
    }
}
```

I need to sum all 'aa' together and 'bb' as well.
Should be something like

```
var res = {
    aa: 18,
    bb: 254
}
```

Comment: There are no "methods" in the object you posted. Those are called "properties".

Comment: Will the `aa` and `bb` be the same always, or there will be other keys as well?

Comment: No, all properties are the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var obj = {
    a: {
        aa: 12,
        bb: 4
    },
    b: {
        aa: 5,
        bb: 100
    },
    c: {
        aa: 1,
        bb: 150
    }
};

var result = _.chain(obj)
  .values()
  .reduce(function (c, p) {
    return _.mapObject(c, function (value, key) {
       return p[key] + value;  
    });
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `_.reduce`

```
_.reduce(obj, function(total, element) {
      total.aa = total.aa + element.aa; 
      total.bb = total.bb + element.bb; 
      return total;
}, { aa: 0, bb: 0})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a few ways of doing it:
Using two loops:

```js
var obj = {
    a: {
        aa: 12,
        bb: 4
    },
    b: {
        aa: 5,
        bb: 100
    },
    c: {
        aa: 1,
        bb: 150
    }
};

var result = {};
_.each(obj, function(chd) { 
    _.each(chd, function(val, key) { 
      result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + val;
    } );    

} );
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.reduce(obj, function(total, element) {
  return {
    aa: total.aa + element.aa,
    bb: total.bb + element.bb
  };
}, { aa: 0, bb: 0});
```

Comment: um... you copied my answer

Comment: I'm sorry. It wasn't my intention. I guess we both found the same answer... Do you want me to delete it?

Comment: no, theres a few other repeats, many ways to do the same thing :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's one solution:

```
var res = _.reduce(obj, function(sum, o) {
  sum.aa += o.aa;
  sum.bb += o.bb;
  return sum;
});
```

Comment: This won't work because `sum.aa` is not defined for the first iteration.

Comment: @ErikEscobedo but did you try to run it?

Comment: add third parameter `{aa:0,bb:0}`

Comment: @lyjackal both Underscore and Lodash are pretty smart if you're passing an object to `reduce()`

Comment: Ah, didn't realize. I think that you might still get `NaN` for values by trying to add a number to `undefined`

Comment: @lyjackal fair enough, I'm just providing an answer to the question without concerning myself with any additional (unmentioned) requirements ;-)